# sec authorize it doesn't work on spring security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm trying to integrate my SpringMVC and Thymeleaf project with Spring Security. I found that this question is usual but I tried the solutions and no one works for me.

I added the org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine class to my configuration but it didn't work.

spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd">


<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">  
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
</http>


    <authentication-manager>  
      <authentication-provider>  
        <user-service>  
        <user name="usuario" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />  
        </user-service>  
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
      </authentication-provider>  
    </authentication-manager>  

<beans:bean id ="passwordEncoder" 
class = "org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder" factory-method = "getInstance" />

<beans:bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
  <beans:property name="additionalDialects">
    <beans:set>
      <beans:bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect"/>
    </beans:set>
  </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">


<head>      
    <title>Home</title>

</head>

<body

    <div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">Text visible to user.</div>
    <div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">Text visible to admin.</div>
        <div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
            Text visible only to authenticated users.
        </div>
        <h4>Spring security.</h4>

</body>

</html>
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

It show all this content to the users before you login it.
Please, can you help me?

Comment: Did you try this version thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5?

Comment: I can't because my project has the 4.3 version of spring

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of version.

Page:

```
xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5"
        :
<div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')">..</div>
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try using the hasAuthority instead of hasRole?

```
sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ADMIN')"
```

It seems, that `hasRole` doesn't work for Spring 4.